# Not able to set textarea and checkbox to set value in mvc5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I am trying to set my value in javascript + jquery in mvc 5 for textarea and checkbox but it is not working.

My javscript code is as

```
 document.getElementById("UpdatetxtDescription").value = "abc";       
 document.getElementById("UpdateActive").checked = true;
```

my view page code is as

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "UpdatetxtDescription" } })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "UpdateActive" } })
```

In console I am able to see

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Active field is required." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, id = UpdateActive }" id="Active" name="Active" type="checkbox" value="true">

<textarea cols="20" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, id = UpdatetxtDescription }" id="Description" name="Description" rows="2"></textarea>
```

I can set value with id="Description" and id="Active" nut as I have 2 checkbox and 2 text area I can not make that id use because both the control have same id as decription for textarea and Active for checkbox

2nd textarea and checkbox are as below whose Id I have set as different

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtDescription", rows = "3" } })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtDescription" } })
```

but in console I can see there Id as

```
<textarea cols="20" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, id = txtDescription, rows = 3 }" id="Description" name="Description" rows="2"></textarea>
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Active field is required." htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, id = txtDescription }" id="Active" name="Active" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Comment: You code for generating the form controls is wrong - its `@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, { @class = "form-control", id = "UpdatetxtDescription" })` (not `new { htmlAttributes = { ...`), then your selector will work correctly, but your code suggest your generating 2 controls for the same property will will never work correctly anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `id` should be unique in the same document for a valid structure, if you can't change it so you could deal with this duplication using jQuery selectors like :

```
$('[id="Description"]:eq(0)') //Select the first element with id "Description"
$('[id="Description"]:eq(1)') //Select the second element with id "Description"
```

The same thing for the second element `input` :

```
$('[id="Active"]:eq(0)') //Select the first element with id "Active"
$('[id="Active"]:eq(1)') //Select the second element with id "Active"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I set value over here $('[id="Description"]:eq(1)').val('abc')  and $('[id="Active"]:eq(1)').checked(true)  Like this?

Comment: I have one issue in this if u can help me out. once I set value of checkbox as true like this  $('[id="Active"]:eq(1)').prop('checked', Active.toLowerCase()); then it never get set to false and one set to false it never get set to true.  I am handling this in javascript.Jquery.

Comment: If you want to set it to `false` you could use `$('[id="Active"]:eq(1)').removeAttr('checked')`.

Comment: once it set to false it never set to true

Comment: @Xtremcool having duplicate `id` is invalid HTML. Your javascript is fine.The problem is with the `cshtml`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `htmlAttributes` parameter of your HTML Helpers the wrong way. If you see the generated HTML, you can see that `id` and `class` are not being set. But an `attribute` called `htmlAttributes` itself is being added like this:

```
<textarea cols="20" htmlattributes="{ class = form-control, id = UpdatetxtDescription }"></textarea>
```

So you should change it to:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", id = "UpdatetxtDescription" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { @class = "form-control", id = "UpdateActive" })
```

and

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Description, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtDescription", rows = "3" })
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Active, new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtDescription" })
```

(PS: If you were to submit this form, only one textarea and checkbox will be bound to model because you are creating more than one input with the same `name`.attribute)